# How can I increase productivity?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I have started building my cross-nation empire but I am struggling with understanding how "productivity" works. Currently I have made myself the following garages:

[image: garages]

As you can see there is a field on the right called *productivity*. This is also shown on the left of the screen:

[image: productivity]

The bit under *current week productivity* says that a garage of this size should be making £150k per week whereas I'm actually only making £57k.

How can I increase the productivity of my garages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Productivity pretty much goes up with time. I haven't found any other answers to this. As your drivers get more and more experienced, they get more and more jobs which makes more money.

Productivity is pretty much the money your garage makes based on how much a fully equipped garage should make. **Upgrading your trucks** and **having good drivers** are the most relevant conditions I have found so far.

Answer (score 5):

I have noticed that your productivity increases as your drivers stats increase. I found that by setting *Driver Training* to long distance first, (all five levels) then change to *ADR* when complete from there I just went down the list until all the boxes were lit. Obviously as they progress down the lists their level and productivity increases and the higher price per load they can command.

I have a full complement of drivers (113) and a tad over £25m I own 46 large garages (17 of them without staff or trucks) and the money just pours in. The biggest problem is that your drivers seldom manage to backload and run back empty. Whereas I will just pick the highest value per km/mile load and transport it to its destination. As I do all this travelling the profits just continue to rise (as do the costs and wages bills) but it seems to work for me.

Unfortunately, now I find I cannot manage every garage I own (my goal was to obviously own and manage every garage in the game but now I find it isn't possible). What a let down, I now ask myself what was the point?